# print i Vs. print "#{i} in Ruby? Is there a difference without adding it to a string?

Tags: ruby

I am a little confused between both of the below in codeacademy examples and want to understand well & know:

- What is the difference between both?
- Is there a time I should use one instead the other?

For Example:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]

array.each do |x|
  x += 10
  print x     #thats what I mean x only not "{x}" as below
end
```

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]

array.each do |x|
  x += 10
  print "#{x}"
end
```

Is that because they consider to add it as variable with string??

Comment: It's a good question (+10) but you could simplify your example to, say, `i = 1` then `print i` versus `print "#{i}"`. Looping over an array of integers doesn't add anything and therefore is a (minor) distraction.

Answer (score 3):

`print x` and `print "#{x}"` are the same

Arguments of [`print`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-print) that aren't strings will be converted by calling their `to_s` method

It means that `print x` is the same as `print x.to_s`, but `x.to_s` is the same as `"#{x}"` (`to_s` is applied to the interpolation result)

Due to brevity, it is usually customary to use without interpolation. But if you wish to concatenate some other object, use interpolation (i.g. `print "#{x}#{y}"`)

Comment: Short and sweet!

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between `x` and `"#{x}"`?

##### print x

The `x` returns the value in whatever type it is. If it is an `integer`, it will return an integer.

In your first example, it IS an `integer` So, the value returned by `x` is an `Integer` type value.

To check what type it is, you can do:

```
print x.class # returns the class which the value belongs to.
```

##### print "#{x}"

The `x` returned here, is first converted into a `string`, no matter whatever type it is. If it is an `integer`, it will still return the value in `string` type. This is called String Interpolation. You can read more about it [here](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html).

In your other example, x IS an `integer`. But at the time of printing it, the value `"#{x}"` is returned as a `string`.

To check what type it is, you can do:

```
print "#{x}".class # returns the class which the value belongs to.
```

> Is there a time I should use one instead the other?

Is that because they consider to add it as variable with string??
Yes, that is one of the reasons we want String Interpolation.

Comment: Thanks a million Anas for such clarification :)

Comment: "So, the value returned by `print x` is an `Integer` type value." – No, it is not. The value returned by `print x` is `nil`.

Comment: Thanks @JörgWMittag for pointing that out. I've updated it. Feel free to add/edit any more details.